# Split-plot design analysis by Linear Mixed Models in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, experiment-design, blocking, split-plot

I am trying to analyse data from a Split-Plot experiment by Linear Mixed Models with lme4 in R. The design consists of a whole-plot factor and two split-plot factors (see attached layout). Whole-plot factor, named Rainfall has two levels (30% reduced and non-reduced Rainfall). The two split-plot factors are Species (levels: A and B) and Culture (levels: monoculture and competition, competition meaning A or B growing with other species). 30% of Rainfall is reduced at the whole-plot level (purple rectangle as an example) using a rainout shelter for each repetition.

Due to logistic and economic limitations, Rainfall was not randomized and was assigned to rows systematically. Species and culture were randomized in subplots within the plots. Biomass, the dependent variable, was sampled at the subplot level.

I am interested in testing the main effects of rainfall, species, and culture as well as their interactions on biomass production.

Could I consider the red rectangle as block, although Rainfall was not randomized within it? I would then have 10 blocks.

How should I set the random effects of the model?

Any comments/ideas would be really helpful. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Based on my limited understanding, it looks like you have wholeplots-subplots-subsubplots, with the treatments applied at the subsubplot level.  Since the treatments are assigned in groups of 4, each group of 4 is a 'block' or subplot. Random effects would be subplot nested within wholeplot. 4 WP, 20 SP, 80 SSP. lmer() code for main effects and 2-way interactions should be something like: lmer(b ~ r+s+c+r:s+r:c+s:c+(1|WP/SP))

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. Could I ask why you consider WP as a grouping factor? Do you consider that each SP within WP are pseudoreplicates? Although the rainfall factor is not randomized, I would consider each SP as independent replicates. The Rainfall reduction was applied to each SP with independent rainout shelters. I am trying with the following code:  lmer(b ~ r*s*c+(1|SP). I tried including replicate (the red rectangle, there are 10 of them) as fixed or random factor but it does not explain more variance, SP seem to capture all the explained variance of the random factors.

Comment: I'll redo terminology, since my wp-sp-ssp was an attempt to describe the structure different from yours, but I might have just added confusion. So I'll use row-purple-mixed(colors). If rainfall was assigned to units (usually randomized) at the purple level, then they would be the 'largest' level unit. However, you said they were assigned per _row_ of purples, not to the purples themselves. That means that row-to-row variability would be the 'noise'(error) against which the 'signal' effect of rainfall is compared. Purples are grouped within rows.

Comment: Stephen Senn has written some great stuff on block structure and treatment structure that I _highly_ recommend. He also covers it, a bit, about 1/3 of the way into https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTrVhIwy8e8 "70 Years Old and Still Here: The Randomized Clinical Trial and its Critics". As for the R code, if you add a (simulated?) dataset to your Question I'll see if I can take a look.